# Arrendondamento para cima

Tags: c#, .net, arredondamento

Eu tenho este valores, onde `contrato.Count = 63` e `63/50 = 1.26`. Gostaria que arrendondasse para `2`, estou fazendo desta forma:

```
 decimal arrendondamento = contrato.Count / 50;
 var valorArredondado = Math.Ceiling(arrendondamento);
```

Mas sempre me traz 1.

Comment: Mas para arredondar para 2 o valor não deveria ser maior que 1.50?

Comment: Então, por isso preciso verificar, pois sempre precisa ser para cima.

Comment: 1.01 também ficaria 2? 1.00 ficaria 1 né?

Comment: Isso. Pois eu preciso gerar um lote, se der 1.01 quer dizer que ainda tem algo para gerar, e por isso precisa ser para cima.

Comment: A o resultado de 2 números inteiros é sempre um número inteiro. Tenta fazer converter os números para decimal e verifica o retorno.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O resultado da divisão de dois números inteiros sempre será um número inteiro (no .Net).
Sendo assim se converter os valores para decimal e usar o `Math.Ceiling` você terá o valor arredondado para cima.

```
Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDecimal(63)/ Convert.ToDecimal(50));
```

Comment: Converti para decimal, e deu certo.

Comment: Essa conversão é desnecessária. 
No caso de literais basta acrescentar sufixo `m` para que o compilador interprete a divisão de decimais: `Math.Ceiling(63m / 50m);`. No caso de variáveis e constantes só fazer casting da operação `Math.Ceiling((Decimal)  varA / varB)`. [Código no Fiddlel](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wQXDZa)

Comment: Essa do sufixo eu não conhecia, bem legal e pratica.

Comment: @AugustoVasques +1: Ótima colocação. Só uma correção: o casting que usou de exemplo não é da operação, é do operando `varA`, se fosse da operação o valor seria o resultado inteiro da operação "castado" como `decimal`.

Answer (score 6):

Para arredondar para cima use o método estático [Math.Ceiling](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=netframework-4.8) que aceita um `Decimal` ou `Double` e retorna o menor valor inteiro maior ou igual ao número decimal especificado(arredonda para cima).

**Exemplo:**

```
using System;

class MainClass {

  public static void Main (string[] args) {

    double[] valores = {7.03, 7.64, 0.12, -0.12, -7.1, -7.6};

    Console.WriteLine("  Valor          Ceiling\n");

    foreach (var valor in valores)
       Console.WriteLine("{0,7} {1,16}", valor, Math.Ceiling(valor));
  }

}
```

---

```
         Valor          Ceiling          
          7.03                8              
          7.64                8              
          0.12                1              
         -0.12                0             
          -7.1               -7             
          -7.6               -7
```

[Código no Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ConcernedMenacingComputeranimation).

Answer (score 6):

O diagnóstico das outras respostas está correto, porém o prognóstico não é o melhor. A forma mais simples, e diria mais correta porque evita conversão, de fazer isto é assim:

```
decimal arrendondamento = contrato.Count / 50M;
var valorArredondado = Math.Ceiling(arrendondamento);
```

Desta forma você tem um número como decimal e a divisão ocorre respeitando isto sem precisar converter nada que é ineficiente e verboso. Note que o problema é a tipagem na divisão, o método de arredondamento não interfere nisto, por isso fiz um código que mostra o resultado sem aplicá-lo também:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var contador = 63;
        decimal arrendondamento = contador / 50M;
        WriteLine(arrendondamento);
        WriteLine(Ceiling(arrendondamento));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Cb5r7h). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rfdxQ4). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/Division.cs).